# Display Custom video ads on native android videoPlayer like on Youtube

Tags: android, android-studio, android-video-player, video-ads, imasdk

I just want to know that is it possible to display custom video ads on native videoPlayer . iwas doing R&D on this topic and got IMA SDk from google developers .

link given bellow :-

https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/quickstart

i downloaded it's sample and make them run on my system they are exactly doing the same thing which i want. i studied the code and found that they are using special type od URL to display their video ,So my first question is that how to get that URL and is that free to make ?

or i need to use framelayout and have to build my custom Ui for achieving that.

The point is i have my store and i want to implement only my store videos as ads on native video player in my application.I am new to this approach and trying to found good solution .Therefore i am here to seek some guidance from you experts.

Any help will be appreciated , Please do provide me some suggestions, i will be very grateful to you.

Regards

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: yes, I used IMA sdk for this functionality.

Comment: And you got the same video ads that youtube has?

Comment: @Sonunegi were you able to play your own store videos using the IMA sdk? Can you please clarify that part?